# BRNN implementation issue

Tags: neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

I am trying to implement bidirectional RNN from scratch and have the issue with it.
Let's assume we have implemented RNN cell with given number of hidden units, in this case the forward pass for BRNN will be the next (pseudocode):

```
def brnn_forward(input):
    hiddden_state = RNN.forward(input)
    reversed_input = reverse(input)
    hiddden_state_reversed = RNN.forward(reversed_input)
    output = concatenate(hiddden_state, hiddden_state_reversed)
    return output
```

But then I don't know how to implement backward pass. I get derivative error dA (shape = (hidden_units, batch_size, times)) from the next layer with the shape of forward pass output (assuming of course we didn't have concatenation of outputs which doubled amount of hidden units after forward pass). 
However the standard RNN cell backward function takes dA with the shape of forward input, so I've tried:

```
def brnn_backward(dA):
    h = number_of_hidden_units
    d_hiddden_state = RNN.backward(dA[:h,:,:])
    d_hiddden_state_reversed = RNN.backward(dA[h:,:,:])
    dA_for_previous_layer = d_hiddden_state+d_hiddden_state_reversed
    return dA_for_previous_layer
```

But it didnt work and gave me results worse then with unidirectional RNN. 
Also I am not sure how to find derivative error for previous layer (in case we have embedding layer before for instance). Could someone help with backward pass?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, backward and forward in `BiRNN` are the same process, their difference is the sequence of input.

You don't need to implement a specific function for forward or backward cell, just create a normal `RNN cell`, give input states and get output states. In forward chain, you could pass normal input sequence into it, and pass a reverse sequence of input in backward chain.

If you have time, you could read the code how TensorFlow implement `BiRNN` based on normal `RNN`. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L315